# Show new view in Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have Ext.tab.Panel with few items. One item is login panel of type Ext.form.Panel.From controller I call Ext.Ajax.request to login. From callback method i would like to show new view(logged in). I mean on the same tab replace tab content login form view with new view (Ext.List/Ext.Panel)

Can someone guide me how to make it? I did't found correct functions in Ext.tab.Panel docs.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setActiveItem` method for TabPanel (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel)